# Execution after Async method not running

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, mvvm, task

I have this method in my ViewModel:

```
private async void InicializarModulo(IModuloNeotek modulo)
{
    var t = _service.InitializeModuloAsync(DataProvider.NombreInstanciaSqlServer,
            modulo, Empresa.NombreEmpresa);
    ServiceResult<IModuloNeotek> sResult = await t;

    if (sResult.HasErrors)// this never runs
        MessageBox.Show("Error"); 
}
```

This is my service call:

```
public async Task<ServiceResult<IModuloNeotek>> InitializeModuloAsync(string dataSource,
    IModuloNeotek modulo, string nombreEmpresa)
{
    return await Task.Run(() => InitializeModulo(dataSource, modulo, nombreEmpresa));
}
```

EDIT:

```
public ServiceResult<IModuloNeotek> InitializeModulo(string dataSource, IModuloNeotek modulo, string nombreEmpresa)
{
    ServiceResult<IModuloNeotek> sResult;
    if (DatabaseExists(dataSource, Strings.GetDbName(nombreEmpresa, modulo.NombreModulo)))
        {
            sResult = new ServiceResult<IModuloNeotek>(null);
            sResult.Error =
                string.Format(
                    "El modulo {0} ya esta inicializado para esta empresa.",
                    modulo.NombreModulo);
            return sResult;
        }
        SqlQueryResult qResult = new SqlQueryResult();
        string connString = GenerateConnectionString(dataSource);

        switch (modulo.NombreModulo)
        {
            case "Contabilidad":
                qResult = ExecuteScript(connString, GetScriptStream(TipoModulo.Contabilidad, nombreEmpresa));
                if (qResult.Result)
                {
                    string query =
                        string.Format("INSERT INTO Modulos (NombreModulo, Inicializado, EmpresaId)" +
                                      "VALUES ('{0}', 'true', (SELECT IdEmpresa FROM Empresas WHERE NombreEmpresa=" +
                                      "'{1}')) ", modulo.NombreModulo, nombreEmpresa);

                    qResult = ExeCuteQuery(query, dataSource, Resources.MaterDbName);
                    if (qResult.Result)
                    {
                        sResult = new ServiceResult<IModuloNeotek>(modulo);
                        return sResult;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "Proveedores":
                break;
            case "Produccion":
                break;
        }
        sResult = new ServiceResult<IModuloNeotek>(null);
        sResult.Error = qResult.Error;
        sResult.InnerError = qResult.InnerError;
        return sResult;
}
```

So, why it is not continuing execution? I tried everything, returning a Task from service and awaiting in ViewModel, not returning `Task.Run`, simply the task, I dont know that to do, any clues? thanks

Comment: Show definition of `InitializeModulo(dataSource, modulo, nombreEmpresa)`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
private async void InicializarModulo(IModuloNeotek modulo)
```

to:

```
private async Task InicializarModulo(IModuloNeotek modulo)
```

Comment: I dont know what is happening, I already used this same pattern and worked, now it doesnt!

Comment: Try debugging your code and catching the exception inside the task by putting `try { ... code here ... } catch (Exception ex) { }`

Comment: Also, is your main thread still running or does it exit before the task is completed?
You might have to wait for the task to finish so that your main thread will keep running.

Comment: How do I know that? I only know that the code is not reached

Comment: No, not catching anything

Comment: You can simply check it by printing a trace message right before the main thread's scope is ended and another message before the part that is never reached and check which one is printed before the other.

Comment: How do I print a trace message...?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("message here")` if it's a console application. If not, you can print to a file.

You can also add a `Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);` before the main thread is ended to check if this is indeed the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Your service call is incorrect. It is already `awaiting` itself.

Update to not `await`.

```
private async void InicializarModulo(IModuloNeotek modulo)
{
    var t = _service.InitializeModuloAsync(DataProvider.NombreInstanciaSqlServer, modulo, Empresa.NombreEmpresa);
    ServiceResult<IModuloNeotek> sResult = await t;

    if (sResult.HasErrors)// this never runs
        MessageBox.Show("Error"); 
}

public Task<ServiceResult<IModuloNeotek>> InitializeModuloAsync(string dataSource, IModuloNeotek modulo, string nombreEmpresa)
{
    return Task.Run(() => InitializeModulo(dataSource, modulo, nombreEmpresa));
}
```

Comment: Ok, I had an error in my DataProvider not suplying the Sql Server Name, I fixed it and now it works, but why I was getting no errors? I dont get it

Comment: Not sure why you weren't getting errors. Were they 'first chance exceptions'? usually with those, they are non-breaking at runtime.

Comment: @LuchoMansilla - It's because the exception was occurring in the InicializarModulo task, and since it's not the main thread, and nothing was there to catch it, you weren't prompt that an exception has occurred.